# Mythfrontend keeps loosing it's settings on reboot

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv, ltsp

I'm using Mythbuntu 12.04 and I have it setup as a LTSP server.

When I boot a fat-client as my 'mythfrontend' it asks me the normal questions, language, server, username, password, then it saves that in the .mythtv/mysql.txt file. When I reboot my client it resets that file back to default. Why does mythtv or ltsp do this?

The work around I use at the moment is to create a sript called ~/bin/start_myth with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

cp ~/mysql.txt ~/.mythtv
mythfrontend
```

The ~/mythtv.txt file holds the correct settings. I would like to remove this workaround and find out what exactly is causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a couple of things.  First, is your LTSP overlay working correctly?  Are other files saved as appropriate when you reboot?  If not, you'll need to get your overlay working correctly on your server and mounted on your client.  Look into doing a dpkg-reconfigure mythbuntu-diskless-server on your LTSP server.

If it is working correctly, could your just symlink the two files in the client chroot?

Comment: I had a heap of problems running the ltsp-build-client with the '--fat-client' switch instead. However this gives me no overlay to play around with.